# checking two values on 'enter' press

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check the value of a input field against a value in my js object on pressing enter. the `if (document.getElementById("barcode").value === element.anr)` works. however, i only want it to execute `document.getElementById("next").click();` if barcodecounter is equal to `element.menge`.

Basically if `element.menge` has a value of 5, the first time `document.getElementById("barcode").value` is equal to `element.anr` I want `barcodecounter` to increase by 1 and when its equal to `element.menge` it should execute `document.getElementById("next").click();`.

Currently if e.g. `element.menge` is 5, it still executes `document.getElementById("next").click();` even when I only provided it once instead of 5 times.

What am I doing wrong?

```
document.getElementById("barcode").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        let barcodecounter;
        if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
            if (document.getElementById("barcode").value === element.anr) {
                barcodecounter++;
                if (barcodecounter = element.menge) {
                    document.getElementById("next").click();
                }
                console.log(document.getElementById("barcode").value, element.anr);
                console.log(element.menge);
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("barcode").value != element.anr){
                alert("Falscher Artikel");
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: `barcodecounter = element.menge` should be `===` (or `==`)

Comment: I've tried that but then it doesn't do anything. Do I have to declare `element.anr` as a int?

Comment: Try this: `console.log(barcodecounter); console.log(element.menge); if (barcodecounter == element.menge) { console.log('equal'); document.getElementById("next").click(); } else { console.log('different'); }` and check that everything has the value that you expect.

Comment: Also only click next if there is a document with a higher index than barcodeCounter

Comment: Removed the json tag as there was nothing in the question about JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an assignment `=` not a boolean compare `==`, simple change.  I also added some adjustments to the code to initialize stuff. `element` might be something else but was not in there

```js
// used this but not declared:
//let element = {};
//element.anr = 0;
//element.menge = 0;
//OR use, I assume numerics heres
let element = {
  anr: 0,
  menge: 0
};
document.getElementById("barcode").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  let barcodecounter = 0;// set initial value;
  if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
    if (document.getElementById("barcode").value === element.anr) {
      barcodecounter++;
      if (barcodecounter == element.menge) {
        document.getElementById("next").click();
      }
      console.log(document.getElementById("barcode").value, element.anr);
      console.log(element.menge);
    } else /* no need for else if here */ {
      alert("Falscher Artikel");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: There might be other things but in the question context this is all I saw